# Book style does wrong page shift

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm writing my thesis in LaTeX and i'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
```

but I have a problem. I want, as in books, that the odd pages are shift to the right and even pages to the left. In my code-created pdf happen the opposite. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean if you look in something like two page view in a pdf viewer? Pdf viewers are not always too sensible about that, but you can add a  blank page 0 at the start to change the parity in such cases.

Comment: Some PDF viewers also have a switch when in two-page mode, to allow you to place the odd-numbered pages on the left or (more correctly) right of the pair. Usually, the default setting is Wrong

Comment: BTW, in most decently-typeset books, the outer margins (right margin on right-hand page) are wider than the inner margins. Do you want to do the opposite?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I know how to add a blank page but I don't know how to numbering it 0. Can you help me?

Comment: To Brent.Longborough, yeah I want the opposite. On right-hand pages the inner margin must be wider than the outer margin. And on left-handed pages the dual.

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate as it is about page viewers not about the margins. Voted to re-open

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok. voted.

Answer (score 4):

The title is misleading: the book class *doesn't* do wrong shifting. The most common practice in typography is to have wider outer margins than inner ones.

However, your problem is easily solvable with the help of the `geometry` package: just tell it what your margins should look like:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{outer=1cm,inner=3cm}
```

Not that I recommend this. If you want equal margins after reserving a binding correction, which I don't recommend either, you can do

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=0.7cm,hratio=1:1}
```

You'll probably have to set also the top and bottom margins to your liking.